# How to create create a 3d structure using gl.POINTS in webgl?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a big set of coordinates that corresponds to a 3d structure which i want to create in webgl and i think i can do it with:

```
gl.drawArray(gl.POINTS, 0, 3);
```

but the thing is that the i am unable to create the code, can anyone please provide a code that help me create that structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quickly render your data in 3D then I recommend you use a 3rd party library between your app and WebGL, such as three.js or Unity.

If you want to use WebGL directly, then I have appended a tiny functioning WebGL program.  You can use it as a starting point to learn WebGL.

If your 3D data is a point cloud then you can make and select a buffer of XYZ coordinates, and then use "gl.drawArray(gl.POINTS, 0, nv)".

If your 3D data contains surfaces then you need to represent your surface as many triangles, load the vertices into a buffer, and then use gl.TRIANGLES instead of gl.Points.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tiny WebGL</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="chart" style="width:512px; height:512px; border:1px solid #000;">
    <script>
        function makeShader(type, src) {
            var shader = gl.createShader(type);
            gl.shaderSource(shader, src);
            gl.compileShader(shader);
            if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
                alert("WebGL compiled failed");
            return shader;
        }

        function makeProgram(vs, fs) {
            var prog = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(prog, makeShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vs));
            gl.attachShader(prog, makeShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fs));
            gl.linkProgram(prog);
            if (!gl.getProgramParameter(prog, gl.LINK_STATUS))
                alert("WebGL link failed");
            return prog;
        }

        // Setup WebGL with 1-1 pixels
        var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
        var cw = canvas.clientWidth;
        var ch = canvas.clientHeight;
        var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
        canvas.width = cw * dpr;
        canvas.height = ch * dpr;
        var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

        // Make GLSL program
        var vs =
                "attribute float a;" +
                "void main(void) {" +
                "  gl_Position=vec4(a, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);" +
                "  gl_PointSize=64.0;" +
                "}";
        var fs =
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "void main(void) {" +
                "  gl_FragColor=vec4(gl_PointCoord,0.0,1.0);" +
                "}";
        var prog = makeProgram(vs, fs);

        // Bind attrib "a" in location 0, to avoid performance warning.
        gl.bindAttribLocation(prog, 0, "a");
        var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(1), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, 0, 0);

        // Draw scene
        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.useProgram(prog);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
    </script>
</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```